# Can't get rid of twitter from iOS7 lock screen

Tags: ios, twitter

Since upgrading to iOS7 on my iPhone the lock screen is bombarded with Tweets. I want to turn this off as I am sure it kills the battery and is annoying. I turned off twitter in the notification center but it had no effect.

How can I turn this off?

Comment: Are you using a specific twitter client? If so you may have to go into that client's settings.

Comment: Try deleting the app and redownloading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to disable notifications for the specific client that you are using by going to **Settings** → **Notification Center** and tapping on your Twitter client, then disabling **Show on Lock Screen**.

[image: Show on Lock Screen]

---

If you are using the official Twitter app, you can change notification settings by opening the app and going to **Me** → **Settings** button → **Settings** → **Notifications**.

[image]

Comment: I can't see this notification screen in the official Twitter app. I'm getting crappy "recommended" style notifications. Or notifications that three people I know shared the same tweet. How do I turn off only those?